# Coldfusion: QueryOfQueries or adding QueryColumn to display results based on DB query AND calculated value thereof

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have searched extensively but am unable to find something that applies to my task - fully aware that it could be my search terms not leading to a result, so I am grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Application Server: Coldfusion Application Server 10 Enterprise (U13)
Database: mySQL 5 Community Edition

Task: Show list of suitable machines based on user input.

The user inputs certain parameters which are calculated and then retrieved from the mySQL database. This is step 1 and works fine:

```
<cfquery name="qmodells" datasource="dproducts">
SELECT idproduct,mymodell,kw1,mymodellprice
FROM myproducts 
WHERE kw1 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC1#"/>
AND kw2 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC2#"/>
ORDER BY mymodellprice ASC
```

After retrieving these values, I can calculate the "machineruntime" of those machines (much simplified formula below). And if the calculated runtime is between one and three hours, I show the result. But to do so, I require the values from the database query:

`<table class="table table-condensed">
    <cfoutput query="qmodells">
    <cfset machineruntime = "#2*(qmodells.kw1/(qmodells.kw2/konstantK3))^konstantK4/24#">
    <cfif #TimeFormat(machineruntime, "HH:mm")# GT "01:00" AND #TimeFormat(machineruntime, "HH:mm")# LT "03:30">
    <tr>
     <td nowrap="">#qmodells.mymodell#</td>
     <td nowrap="">#qmodells.kw1#</td>
     <td nowrap="">#qmodells.machineruntime#</td>
    </tr>

   </cfif>
</cfoutput>
 </table>`

My goal is to show only the first matching machine that runs longer than one hour, possible also the next two results. I can obviously add CSS hidden to any row outside these results, but how would one properly do this?

Should I re-populate a query and then output that, or is there a clever way to iterate through the results and do this more elegantly? All my attemps of calculating within the first query just give me the same runtime for all machines, clearly I am doing it wrong.

I was thinking/trying something like this in the SELECT part of the query:

```
#2*(qmodells.kw1/(qmodells.kw2/konstantK3))^konstantK4/24# AS machineruntime
```

And also using the query as the base for a second query, like so:

```
<cfquery name="topmatch" dbtype="query">
SELECT *
FROM qmodells
WHERE machineruntime > 0.0416666666667
```

THANKS FOR ANY HELP IN THIS!

Comment: *much simplified formula* Is it not possible to do the logic in the initial query or via a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calc attempt which uses *qmodells.kw2* above will grab the only first row of the query as it is not in a loop. Here's my guess at what I *think* you are trying to do.

First run your qModells query as above but let's add a row as a placeholder:

```
<Cfquery ...>
SELECT idproduct,mymodell,kw1,kw2,mymodellprice, 0.0 AS machineruntime
FROM myproducts 
WHERE kw1 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC1#"/>
AND kw2 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC2#"/>
ORDER BY mymodellprice ASC
</cfquery>
```

Note I added kw2 to the column list as well because I didn't see where that was coming from - but it seemed logically a part of the query (since k1 was in the column list).

Next loop through your query, calculate and set the machine run time.

```
<cfloop query="#qmodels#">

    <cfset mymachineruntime = 2*(kw1/(kw2/konstantK3))^konstantK4/24 />
    <cfset querysetcell(qmodels,'machineruntime',mymachineruntime,currentrow)/>
</cfloop>
```

Finally, using q of a q, select the record matching the values you are looking for:

```
<cfquery name="topmatch" dbtype="query">
SELECT *
FROM qmodells
WHERE machineruntime > 0.0416666666667
</cfquery>
```

I *think* that is close to what you are trying above. You just need a loop.

---

Note - this is possibly a good spot for a stored procedure or some clever database code in your query. The DB is probably capable of generating this value and returning it for you directly. Hope this helps!

---

EDIT NOTE: As Dan pointed out an empty string might cause problems for you when you try to select via Q of a Q (it might result in AlphaNum selection instead of just Num selection). So I have altered the query to use a number (0).

Comment: Using an empty string as a placeholder for a field that will eventually be numeric might cause problems.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS (all of you) very much!! Mark's solution works great, and I learned the proper use of the querysetcell operation which I think was crucial for solving this. I tried doing the calculation in the query but that did not work for some reason, but many thanks to "cfqueryparam" for providing the SQLfiddle - I am going to revisit that again. Again, all your help was most appreciated! I think I am too new here to mark things as useful or "the answer", but I'll come back when I can! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I generally handle that situation like this:

```
<cfquery name="q1" dsn="somedatabase">
select field1, field2, 10.12314 MachineRunTime
etc
</cfquery>
```

Then loop through the query and calculate MachineRunTime for each row.  You can now use query of query with an order by clause and maxrows attribute to get the stuff you want to display.

Comment: Hi Dan - many thanks for your input! If I understand correctly your  example refers to my first query, i.e. I should introduce "MachineRunTime" as a columnnamne in q1, but simply with a placeholder value (as I have no column with that name? - or should I simply add a column to the table even if it can not hold useful data in the db table)?

Comment: I introduced MachineRunTime as a columnname and gave it a value that represents the desired datatype.  It's simple but somewhat inefficient in that you are transferring more data from your db.  The other way to do it is to use QueryAddColumn().  Simpleton that I am, I often opt for simplicity.

Comment: Cool, I had no idea you could do that so easily. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: One more follow-up question if you have a moment (and then I think I can mark your answer as solved :-) ): q1 works and looks like this: `<cfquery name="q1" datasource="datasourcename">
 SELECT fieldname1,fieldname2, 10.12345 MachineRunTime 
 FROM table1 
</cfquery>`

Comment: When you say: "loop through the query and calculate MachineRunTime for each row, I take it this is not going to cut it: `<cfloop query="q1">
 <cfset MachineRunTime = "#variable1*(q1.mpAh/(variable2/q1.mpv/variable3)/variable4)^constant1/24#">
</cfloop>` as it would keep overwriting it, correct? Do I need to introduce a structure or multi-dimensional array here?

Comment: Based on whatever needs to be in the loop above, I take it this second query q2 should be alright to yield what I need: `<cfquery name="q2" dbtype="query" maxrows="3">
 SELECT *
 FROM q1
 WHERE MachineRunTime > 0.0416666666667
 AND mpw > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.variable5#"/>
 AND mpva > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.variable6#"/>
 ORDER BY MachineRunTime ASC
</cfquery>`

<cfdump var="#q2#">

Comment: Let me know how to send you a virtual beer or box of cookies!

Comment: Mark's answer gives details about what to do in the loop.  As far as the q of q goes, it would be redundant to include filtering that was already applied when querying the database.  Also, the fields mpw and mpva are not in your initial query so you can't use them in q of q.

Comment: Hi all - wow, only now saw the other suggestions - thanks so much. Dan - yes, sorry, in my attempt to take out some "noise" in my first simplified examples I added some real columns back into the mix later, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

As Leigh said, could you do this directly in the query?

```
select model,modelprice,kw1,kw2,
  (2 * (kw1 / (kw2/#val(konstantK3)#))^#val(konstantK4)#/24) as MachineRunTime
  from MyProducts
 WHERE kw1 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC1#"/>
   AND kw2 > <cfqueryparam value="#session.something1.something2.calculatedvalueC2#"/>
```

I made a [basic demonstration sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c081f/7) with very random sample data.

If it's not important that you have the base query data AND the QoQ data, you can append this and nix the QoQ.

```
AND (2 * (kw1 / (kw2/#val(konstantK3)#))^#val(konstantK4)#/24) > 0.0416666666667
```

Because we're working with numbers as the variable input, besides the `cfqueryparams` OP already placed, I just used the #val()# function to convert any non-number to 0. OP, you could do some error-checking outside of the query and say `<cfif val(konstantk3) gt 0 and val(konstantk4) eq 0>...execute the code....</cfif>` as well.

Comment: I suggested that in my comments on my solution as well. I only wondered because he mentioned his example formula was "greatly simplified" - so I though maybe there was more routine we were not seeing.

Comment: Yes, the reason I asked is because I was not sure if they were using CF because it was really necessary - or simply because they were not sure how to implement the SQL. Without knowing more, this does sound like a job for the db (possibly a stored procedure). But ... it is hard to say without seeing the actual logic.